# Optimizing run time in simple vector implementation

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I just started implementing my own vector class and i'm testing it with a simple file to check the time it takes to finish. One test took 2:30 minutes while the others took 90 and 29 seconds.

Something is hitting the performance of this class. Can you help me trace the source?

The test:

```
#include "MyVector.h"

const unsigned int SIZE_V= 1000000;
const unsigned int RUNS= 10000;

int main() {

      MyVector v(SIZE_V);

      for (unsigned int j=0; j<RUNS; ++j) {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<SIZE_V; ++i) {
          v[i]= i;
        }
      }

      return 0;
}
```

The class:

MyVector.h:

```
#ifndef MY_VECTOR_H
#define MY_VECTOR_H

class MyVector {

 public:

      MyVector(unsigned int size);
      ~MyVector();

      int& operator[](unsigned int i);

 private:
      int* _data;
      unsigned int _size;
      MyVector(const MyVector&);
      MyVector& operator=(const MyVector&);

};
#endif
```

MyVector.cpp:

```
#include "MyVector.h"
#include <assert.h>

MyVector::MyVector(unsigned int size) : _data(new int[size]) {
}

MyVector::~MyVector() {
      delete[] _data;
}

int& MyVector::operator[](unsigned int i) {
      assert(i<_size);
      return _data[i];
}
```

**EDIT:**

These are the test results:

```
granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) for 0.04% of 27.09 seconds

index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]    100.0   12.51   14.58                 main [1]
               11.28    0.00 1410065408/1410065408     MyVector::operator[](unsigned int) [2]
                3.31    0.00       1/1           MyVector::~MyVector() [3]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           MyVector::MyVector(unsigned int) [7]
-----------------------------------------------
               11.28    0.00 1410065408/1410065408     main [1]
[2]     41.6   11.28    0.00 1410065408         MyVector::operator[](unsigned int) [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                3.31    0.00       1/1           main [1]
[3]     12.2    3.31    0.00       1         MyVector::~MyVector() [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [1]
[7]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         MyVector::MyVector(unsigned int) [7]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You run a statement 10 _billion_ times and wonder why it takes some time?

Comment: Which test took 2.5 minutes and which one took 90?

Comment: @juanchopanza this took 29 seconds. i tired using only unsigned ints and it got to 2.5 minutes. Maybe something with type conversions?

Comment: a. the test results say that MyVector::operator[] was called 1410065408 times, but the according to the code it should have been 10000000000 times - somthing missing. b. Have you tested with fully optimized code? Statements like assert(i<_size); should not be in tested code, since they can be unpredictable. c. I see you used a profiler, did you measure while the profiler was active? If so the results are meaningless.

Comment: What are differences between the 3 tests you ran?

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance: I think the discrepancy might be down to using a sampling profiler.

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance i used g++ -Wall -O -pg -DNDEBUG when compiling. I measured when the profiler was active :)

Comment: Ok, so do the measurements without profiler and with full optimized code. Repeat more more than 3 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you might want to do is make `operator[]` inline. When I do this, the performance of your code on my box improves threefold from

```
real    0m18.270s
```

to

```
real    0m6.030s
```

In the latter test, each iteration of the test loop takes about 0.6ns (!) or about 1.5 clock cycles.

This is on a Sandy Bridge box using g++ 4.7.2 with `-O3`.

P.S. There's a bug in the code: the constructor doesn't initialize `_size`, so the `assert()` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Tom: By the way, there's a bug in the code: the constructor doesn't initialize `_size`, so the `assert()` has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

1. Measure without profiler running.
2. Measure fully optimized code: `g++ -O3`

Answer (score 0):

You are writing:-

```
1000000 * 10000 * 4 * 8 = 320000000000
```

bits of data in total, in the tests that is:-

```
2.5 mins = 2133333333 bits / sec = ~2,000 MB/s

90 secs = 3555555555 bits / sec = ~3,400 MB/s

30 secs = 10666666666 bits / sec = ~10,000 MB/s
```

DDR2 peak data rates are between 3,200 MB/s amd 8,533 MB/s and DDR3 peak data ranges are between 6,400 MB/s and 17,066 MB/s/

Based on that, I'd say you've got DDR3-1600 ram chips.

Comment: Interesting, but how is this helpful to identify non-optimal code?

Comment: @stefan: Basically, it just checks if you're hitting bandwidth limits, which, given the figures above, is probably the case. This means that any improvements to the code in the example won't speed up the program and you can't tell if the code is optimal or not. Also, I gave peak data rates, you're unlikely to get those figures.